# How many users can Apache Handle?

Tags: apache

When users are increase then Apache needs to restart.but I don't know how many users at that time. I have multiple sites on Apache. So I want to check how many users can handle Apache.

I have used Apache benchmark

```
ab -n 100  -c 10 http://www.example.com
```

but it gives only requests/second and how many seconds require for 100 request.

Comment: see RLimitMEM, RLimitNPROC, MaxKeepAliveRequests etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on the resources apache has available. Apache will run until it runs out of RAM, CPU, DISK or NETWORK.

Comment: I want generate a load on apache for this i want a tool. have you any idea about tool.
i have used httperf tool for generate tools

Comment: For generate load on apache you can use httperf tool. you can use command


 httperf --hog --server=127.0.0.1 --uri "/" --num-conn 30000 --num-call 1 --timeout 5 --rate 500 --port 80

Comment: @AnkitAneja ok thats good. so I was able to answer your question ? can you accept it or you need something else ?

Comment: I want ui tool that gives status of server on ui

Comment: @AnkitAneja then its a different question , please ask a new question asking about a tool to give you the status and ill try to help you